# Interpolate Gradient noise in Julia

Tags: julia, perlin-noise

I'm trying to implement and learn the code from [here](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/noisegen/index.html) but I'm having problems with interpolate it. This is my code from my implementation in Julia:

```
lerp(a, b, w) = a * (1 - w) + b * w

function Noise(x, y)
    n = x + y * 53;
    n = (n << 13) $ n;
    return (1.0 - ( (n * ((n * n * 15731) + 789221) +  1376312589) & 0x7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);
end

function coherentNoise(x,y)
   x₁ = convert(Int64,modf(x)[2])
   y₁ = convert(Int64,modf(y)[2])
   xᵣ = x - x₁
   yᵣ = y - y₁
   q1 = Noise(x₁-1,y₁+1)
   q2 = Noise(x₁+1,y₁+1)
   q3 = Noise(x₁-1,y₁-1)
   q4 = Noise(x₁-1,y₁+1)

   v = lerp(q1,q2,xᵣ)
   v1 = lerp(q3,q4,xᵣ)
   return abs(lerp(v,v1,yᵣ))
   #value = bilinear(q1,q2,q3,q4,x₁,x₁-1,x₁+1,y₁,y₁-1,y₁+1)
   #return abs(value)
end


arr = Array{Float64}(height,width)

for x = 1:height
    for y = 1:width
        nx = x/60
        ny = y/60
        arr[x,y]=coherentNoise(nx,ny)
    end
end
```

this is the result:

[image]

I tried also use this bilinear interpolation function but i get a worse result.

```
# bilinear interpolation
function bilinear(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,x,x1,x2,y,y1,y2)
    R1 = ((x2-x)/(x2-x1))*Q3 + ((x-x1)/(x2-x1))*Q4
    R2 = ((x2-x)/(x2-x1))*Q1 + ((x-x1)/(x2-x1))*Q2
    P = ((y2-y)/(y2-y1))*R1 + ((y-y1)/(y2-y1))*R2
    return P
end
```

the result:

[image]

I don't know if is a problem with the`Noise` function or something else.

## Update

I'm obtaining best results using bilinear interpolation with the next noise generator function:

```
function coherentNoise(x,y,n::Int64)
    #octa3e
    o = 0.25
    #octave x and y
    x /=n
    y /=n 
    #decimal value
    x₁ = x < 0 ? x : x-o
    y₁ = y < 0 ? y : y-o
    x₂ = x+o
    y₂ = y+o
    #calculate corners data
    q1 = abs(Noise(floor(Int64,x₁),floor(Int64,y₂)))
    q2 = abs(Noise(floor(Int64,x₂),floor(Int64,y₂)))
    q3 = abs(Noise(floor(Int64,x₁),floor(Int64,y₁)))
    q4 = abs(Noise(floor(Int64,x₂),floor(Int64,y₁)))
    #bilenear interpolation

    value = bilinear(q2,q1,q4,q3,x,x₁,x₂,y,y₁,y₂)
    return abs(value)
end
```

Result:

[image]

I'm thinking that the problem is how I select the points to do the bilinear interpolation, no idea how to do it right.

## Update 2:

This is the code to generate the images:

```
for x = 1:height
    for y = 1:width
        arr[x,y]=coherentNoise(x,y,50)
    end
end

imwrite(convert(Image,arr),"desktop/projects/julia/Noise/test2.png")
```

## Update 3

Thanks to the answer of [Dan Getz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40097740/3927509) I'm getting a better output but with some weird "worms"

output:

[image]

Comment: do you mind showing the code that produces these plots? :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I added it in the update 2.

Comment: In `coherentNoise(x,y)` on the first listing, `q1 = Noise(x₁-1,y₁+1)` should be `q1 = Noise(x₁,,y₁+1)` without the `-1`. The `x₁` and `y₁` step by 1 when `x` and `y` vary slowly, and the goal is to interpolate the `Noise` function from the corners of 1 unit squares and not 2 unit squares (same applies to following similar lines).

Comment: In `coherentNoise(x,y)` on the first listing, `q1` and `q4` are the same, and should be different corners. Ok... A rewrite of `coherentNoise` is in an answer.

Comment: The "worm" noise seems to me the result of clamping of values to positive i.e. negative values are represented as black. Try to make image out of `0.5*(arr+1.0)`. Any better?

Comment: Ya! now it's working! Thanks you so much. Can you explain me a bit more the `0.5*(arr+1.0)` . And why the Noise function return negative numbers if they are a problem? Thanks! again

Comment: The `Noise` function returns a random number from -1.0 to 1.0, and `coherentNoise` interpolates it smoothly in between the grid points. Therefore, the image is smooth numbers from -1.0 to 1.0. Images need to choose a brightness level which is usually represented as a number from 0.0 to 1.0. So `0.5*(arr+1.0)` transforms the (-1.0,1.0) scale to a (0.0,1.0) scale.

Comment: @DanGetz Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the ability to test the code, this should need verification. Basically, I think your intuition the problem is in the choice of interpolation points is right. This is an attempt to fix it (see also comments).

```
function coherentNoise(x,y)
   x₁,xᵣ = floor(Int64,x),mod(x,1)
   y₁,yᵣ = floor(Int64,y),mod(y,1)
   q00 = Noise(x₁,y₁)
   q10 = Noise(x₁+1,y₁)
   q01 = Noise(x₁,y₁+1)
   q11 = Noise(x₁+1,y₁+1)

   v0 = lerp(q00,q10,xᵣ)
   v1 = lerp(q01,q11,xᵣ)
   noise = lerp(v0,v1,yᵣ)
   return noise
end
```

Notes:

- `q`s renamed to `q00` and such to indicate which corner by the offset to X (first number) and Y (second number).
- The identical `q1` and `q4` fixed.
- `floor` and `mod( ,1)` used instead of `modf` since they choose consistent rounding direction (downward) regardless of sign.
- The `Noise` function should type annotate its parameters to restrict to Int32 values, and the `;` at line ends in this function not needed. This is a hash function, and the same effect could be easily coded with Julia hash function and a little wrapper.

For example:

```
Noise(x,y) = 1.0-2.0*hash((x,y))/typemax(UInt)
```

is a more Julia styled drop-in replacement for `Noise`.

If you try this and comment on bugs, we can try to fixup function.

Comment: Now I'm getting smoothed results, but weirds. Will update the question. Thanks for the noise function.

Comment: Updated, I don't know why I'm getting this kind of "worm" noise. Must be the interpolation technique, if you watch the  first listing worms are present too. So, why no use the bilinear interpolation from the first update?